# group by a dynamic composite key (variable length in the number of fields in the key)

Tags: c#, dynamic, group-by

I need to group a list of items based on composite with variable length (i.e. the number of items in the composite key changes from case to case). I know how group by a fixed number of fields (using `Tuple`), but I can't figure out how to make the grouping composite key to take a variable length. I don't mean that it should change the length during the same "grouping stage". I would like to write it once and use it dynamically (a better alternative to writing *i* methods that take a different number of fields as keys.

Consider this simple class:

```
class SimpleItem
{
    public string TargetField { get; set; }
    public string JoinField { get; set; }
    public string InformationField { get; set; }
    public string Additional { get; set; }
}
```

I can group by multiple keys by using something like:

```
var grouped = simpleList.GroupBy(x => new Tuple<string, string>(x.JoinField, x.TargetField))
             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
```

How can I make this grouping, more specifically this key generation `new Tuple<string, string>(x.JoinField, x.TargetField)`, dynamic? I could have a variable number of fields (in this example from 1 to 4) in the composite key and also different field combinations (a total of 12 possibilities, if I'm not mistaking). Is it even possible?

**EDIT:** I have the freedom of changing all the fields into a single `Dictionary<string, string>`, i.e. have a single dictionary property that stores all other previous properties.